# Merging of multiple excel files in R

Tags: r

I am getting a basic problem in R. I have to merge **72 excel files** with similar data type having same variables. I have to merge them to a single data set in R. I have used the below code for merging but this seems NOT practical for so many files. Can anyone help me please?

```
data1<-read.csv("D:/Customer_details1/data-01.csv")

data2<-read.csv("D:/Customer_details2/data-02.csv")

data3<-read.csv("D:/Customer_details3/data-03.csv")

data_merged<-merge(data1,data2,all.x = TRUE, all.y = TRUE)

data_merged2<-merge(data_merged,data3,all.x = TRUE, all.y = TRUE)
```

Comment: if my solution helped to solve your problem you can accept the answer so we can close the question :)

Answer (score 5):

First, if the extensions are .csv, they're not Excel files, they're .csv files.

We can leverage the `apply` family of functions to do this efficiently.

First, let's create a list of the files:

```
setwd("D://Customer_details1/")

#  create a list of all files in the working directory with the .csv extension
files <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
```

Let's use `purrr::map` in this case, although we could also use `lapply` - updated to `map_dfr` to remove the need for `reduce`, by automatically `rbind`-ing into a data frame:

```
library(purrr)

mainDF <- files %>% map_dfr(read.csv)
```

You can pass additional arguments to `read.csv` if you need to: `map(read.csv, ...)`

Note that for `rbind` to work the column names have to be the same, and I'm assuming they are based on your question.

Comment: You can use `map_df` and avoid the `reduce` step.

Comment: No problem, it looks like you made a small typo though, listing `map_dfr` instead of `map_df`. You might wanna fix it so as to not confuse anyone.

Comment: @beigel Nope, if you look at `?purrr` you'll see that `map_dfr` is the `rbind` version, and `map_dfc` is the `cbind` version. Looking at the underlying formulas `map_df` and `map_dfr` appear to be defined exactly the same (i.e. using `rbind`) though, so you're not wrong that `map_df` is also correct.

Comment: My bad. `map_df` doesn't appear in the docs while `map_dfr` and `map_dfc` do, so I'm guessing the latter two are the preferred way to invoke `map_` since they're more explicit.

Comment: @aninditab Do you have both `purrr` and `dplyr` installed?

Comment: @Mako212 Is there a way to use this method and only map_dfr certain column names in all the files? I have a lot of excel files that have some columns that I want but there are some files that have columns that other files don't have... Any idea how I can do this? Thanks.

Comment: @KWANGER I'd recommend asking a new question for this, because there's more subtlety to this than I can address in a comment. In broad terms, you can either select a common subset of columns before combining into a single table, or create NA values for missing columns in the smaller files, preserving all the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Method I
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
path <- "C:/Users/Downloads"
setwd(path)
fn.import<- function(x) read_excel("country.xlsx", sheet=x)
sheet = excel_sheets("country.xlsx")
data_frame = lapply(setNames(sheet, sheet),  fn.import )
data_frame = bind_rows(data_frame, .id="Sheet")
print (data_frame)
#Method II
install.packages("rio")
library(rio)
path <- "C:/Users/country.xlsx"
data <- import_list(path , rbind=TRUE)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).