# R - Keeping column names after merging multiple .xlsx files

Tags: r, purrr, writexl

I want to merge columns of multiple xlsx files (about 100) which all have the same structure, meaning the all have 5 rows and 2 columns.

I'm using the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46305813/16375831) (with a slight edit to merge the columns instead of rows)

```
library(purrr)
library(writexl)


files <- list.files(pattern="*.xlsx")
mainDF <- files %>% map_dfc(read.xlsx) 

write_xlsx(mainDF, "merge.xlsx")
```

but what I end up with is that the first row of every sheet is now the column name.

**How do I keep the original column names in the merged file?**

Also in the merged file there are new columns named "file" which display the file name, I would like to remove those as well.

Any help would be appreciated :)

**EDIT**

Example: I have file1.xlsx, file2.xlsx looking like

```
Data col1              Data  col2
 x    1                 x     4
 y    3                 y     6
```

and my output is

```
1 4
3 6
```

but my goal is to have mergefile.xlsx

```
Data col1 col2
  x   1    4
  y   3    6
```

Comment: Is the first row of every file blank?

Comment: The first row of the single files contains the column name, but after merging the column names are numbers (data used in the single files)

Comment: are you horizontally binding these files? I mean adding columns horizontally?

Comment: @monte Yes, I guess another way to say it would be to take only the second column of every file and append it to the first file (if that makes sense)

Comment: I suggest you use `map` instead of `map_dfc` so that your `mainDF` is a list whose elements are your excel tables and then use `mainDF %>% reduce(~ full_join(..1, ..2, by = "Data"))` to bind them.

Comment: So if you were to add a 3rd file, will that show as `col3` in final dataframe?

Comment: I would try using the `bind_cols` function from the dplyr package and avoid using the `map_dfc()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that `read.csv` doesn't set colnames of the dataframe that it produces to the headers of the input file. You can use `readr::read_csv` to get this behavior.

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

files <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
dfs <- lapply(files, read_csv)

combined_df <- Reduce(function(x, y) full_join(x, y, by = "Data"), dfs)

write_xlsx(combined_df, "merge.xlsx")
```